# Inner link on foundation title accordion?

Tags: javascript, html, css, zurb-foundation

I'm trying to make links on the Foundation accordion title 
Everything I've tried so far doesn't work and just expand the accordion content.

Here a CodePen where you can see what I exactly want (I make `<span>` in place of `<a>` to show you without breaking the style)

http://codepen.io/lerayj/pen/ZWrXYp

Any idea how to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You can't have links tag in a link tag. Besides, the foundation accordion plugin prevent your link, so you have to use an other way to do it, like changin' the structure and do a specific JS code for it.

Here's a custom way that works for your demand :

```
$("button").click(function(){
  $(this).next('div').slideToggle();
});
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EKQbgG

Comment: hey thanks, it's what I was affraid of. It's kinda sucks from Foundation to didn't think about a bit more complex use of their plugin, the Sticky plugin is also completly unfunctionnal on complex use case... I will try your jQuery hack and i'm validatiing you by tomorrow! ;)